# How Can a Custom Controller Factory Relate to Dependency Injection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am reading this article: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560798/ASP-NET-MVC-Controller-Dependency-Injection-for-Be
The author said that we need to create a custom controller factory cause the default controller factory does not allow parametereless constructor in the controller class in which we are not able to achieve dependency injection. However, I believe that we can create empty constructor with no parameter, and another one which accept parameters and avoid the hassle of creating a custom controller factory as illustrated bellow.

For example in this code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public HomeController()
    {
    } 
    public HomeController(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

I can make ILogger variable in the HomeController class public and when I instantiate a HomeController class:

```
HomeController controller = new HomeController();
```

I put:

```
controller.logger = whatevervalue
```

Just like if when I use:

```
HomeController controller = new HomeController(whatevervalue);
```

I believe with the above I can achieve dependency injection.

So why do I need a custom controller factory in the scenario explained above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The author said that we need to create a custom controller factory cause the default controller factory does not allow parametereless constructor in the controller class in which we are not able to achieve dependency injection.

I think you may have misunderstood this part of the article.  The problem isn't that you can't specify your own constructor, that takes any number of parameters, the problem is that the default controller factory **will only call a controller's default constructor**.  So, to be clear, using your example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public HomeController()
    {
    } 
    public HomeController(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

When instantiating an instance of `HomeController`, the default controller factory will always call this constructor:

```
public HomeController()
```

and not this one:

```
public HomeController(ILogger logger)
```

That means the `ILogger` instance will always be `null`.

So now the question becomes, why does the default controller factory only call the default constructor?  We can answer that by asking another question: how would the default controller factory know which constructor you wanted it to call?  If you say, "well, it could call the one with the most parameters", what would happen if you added a third constructor:

```
public HomeController(IService service)
```

`HomeController` now has three separate constructors, two of which require the same number of arguments.  At this point, the default controller factory doesn't have the information it would need to correctly call the constructor you intended it to - it could only guess.

Therefore, the reason you have to implement your own controller factory is to give you a chance to compose the dependencies your controllers need, so you can then invoke the correct constructors for your controllers yourself.

Comment: I am still confused. I can let the program use the default controller and I can use: controller.logger = whatevervalue

Comment: @AymenKareem By doing that, you'd be trying to make use of a (limited) form of property injection.  The problem with that is it means you no longer have the guarantee that `controller.logger` contains a valid logger, because it can be set to `null` at any point in your controller's life cycle.  By performing the injection in the constructor, you can have guard clauses that check if your dependencies are `null`.  That means whenever your controller has successfully been instantiated (i.e. hasn't thrown an `ArgumentNullException`), you have guaranteed you have an instance of `ILogger`.

Comment: I remember once during my course we used something like a mock repository and created a controller from the default factory with one parameterless constructor and another one with one parameter. And in the unit test we called the constructor with one parameter and passed the fake repository. It worked without the hassle of creating a custom controller factory. How?

Comment: That's because when you're doing something like `var sut = new HomeController(loggerMock);`, you're not going through the default controller factory at all - you're directly instantiating an instance of `HomeController`.

Comment: To add to my above comment, you just need to remember that for any HTTP request MVC receives, the default controller factory - or a custom `IControllerFactory` implementation, if you've created one - will create your controllers for you.  That means you will never be doing something like `var controller = new HomeController(...)` anywhere else to create a controller (with the exception of writing unit tests), and that means you don't have the opportunity to inject the dependencies you need, even for public properties, without using a custom controller factory.

Comment: So this means I don't have to create my custom controller for testing purposes?

Comment: That's right.  If you're wanting to create a custom controller factory, it should be because you want to take advantage of dependency injection as a whole.  Dependency injection isn't limited to just making your classes easier to test - although that is certainly a nice benefit.  It sounds to me like you would benefit from reading more about dependency injection, so I feel the best thing to do is to recommend Mark Seemann's [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Dependency-Injection-NET-Mark-Seemann/dp/1935182501) book to you.